# Selecting first 10 records, then next 10

Tags: c#, neo4j

This cypher return first 10 items. But i dont know how return next 10 items and next and next.....

```
   START n=node(*)
    RETURN n
    ORDER BY n.degree ASC (or DESC)
    LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SKIP` Keyword to skip records.

```
SKIP 10
LIMIT 10
```

above code return records from number 11 to 20.